# AppleTV “Watch Now” doesn't recognize purchased content in library

Tags: macos, ios, appletv, television

Approximately two days ago Apple TV’s Watch Now screen stopped letting me watch the next episode of a show that I own and am watching. Instead it takes me to the rent/buy interface. I can watch the next episode by going to Library and finding the episode, but that is irritating.

This happens across all places I try to use AppleTV, my mac, iPhone, and the Apple TV app on my Roku.

I've tried logging out of my account and back on, but that does not help.

I've tried removing the series from watch now, but when I watch an episode through the library, it returns to watch now (which is what I would like to happen) but only shows a purchase next episode option when it is selected (which is not what I would like to happen)

Comment: Try signing out of the app and/or the iTunes Store, and rebooting.  The Watch Now screen is incredibly finicky...

Comment: Thanks I’ll give that a try. I was hoping to avoid it because my password is irritating to type in on the TV 

Comment: this thread on apple community is kafkaesquely marked "solved" on an "I have this problem also" comment. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251467262

Comment: I'm getting help from apple support on this... looks like it may be that I bought a "complete series" of a show and they stopped selling that item. I can still access it through library, but not watch now. I've elevated the request and asked again, but I'm not sure I'll get a different answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes Apple stops selling an item in the iTunes Store (is it still called that?) and when they do Watch Now stops working as expected. This is the answer I've gotten from multiple chats with Apple representatives.